# Distance Agnostic classifier using deep learning techniques

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision

This might be a challenging classification problem.

In this classification, problem distance plays a major role. Here, the Category of the object would change if the distance factor varies. For example, consider objects like Concrete aggregates i.e. 20 mm (millimeter) and 40 mm. 20 mm aggregates might look like 40 mm aggregates when the picture is taken from a close distance and vice versa. In my case, camera calibration is not possible.

So, Looking for an approach using deep learning techniques I should take to develop a distance agnostic classifier whose accuracy will not be compromised for distance variation factor.

Kindly find some sample images on the following links.

[20mm concrete aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s72cH.jpg)

[40mm concrete aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sx6K8.jpg)

Thanks in advance!